# Concatenating Multiple Large .CSV Files with Varying Structures

Tags: python, r, csv, concatenation

I have approximately 40 .csv files (ranging from approx. 100mb - 600mb) that I would like to concatenate into one single .csv file. The data i'm using has been constructed using a prebuilt R code from FNMA which aggregates larger raw data files into a more manageable format. However, when attempting to concatenate the data files, I receive the following error indicating there is a mismatch in field count between files: *"ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 75 fields in line 10, saw 76"*. I have attempted to essentially inner-join the data vertically in order to resolve this issue as the majority of the fields between files are homogeneous, but I have not found a reasonable solution. I am thinking it may make sense to just trim down the .R code to write the fields I know exist, but I would prefer a solution using Python as this data takes a significant amount of time to process and the prebuilt code is rather hefty. **I will include the Python code I have been attempting to use below (I am happy to share the .R code if requested but it is 600+ lines):**

```
import os
import glob
import pandas as pd
#set working directory
os.chdir("folder directory")

#find all csv files in the folder
#use glob pattern matching -> extension = 'csv'
#save result in list -> all_filenames
extension = 'csv'
all_filenames = [i for i in glob.glob('*.{}'.format(extension))]
#print(all_filenames)

#combine all files in the list
combined_csv = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f) for f in all_filenames ], ignore_index=True, sort=False)
#export to csv
combined_csv.to_csv( "FNMA Data Aggregated.csv", index=False, encoding='utf-8-sig')
combined_csv
```

Comment: Could you share the structure of some of the .csv files?

Comment: @cjdeschene, What operating system are you using? If you are using a *NIX-based operating system, then you can use `cat` or other command line tools.

Comment: @Adilius each file has around 400,000+ records (rows) and 74-76 fields (most of them homogeneous). There is a mix of numeric, string, and date types. Let me know if there are other structural elements you are looking for in particular and i'm happy to share.

Comment: @iembry I'm using Windows 10 and running Python through pip

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your setup...

Let's say you have the following two files, **file1.csv**:

```
c1,c2
1,a
2,b
3,c
```

and **file2.csv**:

```
c1,c3
4,iv
5,v
6,vi
```

Do you expect **stacked.csv** to look like the following?

```
c1,c2,c3
1,a,
2,b,
3,c,
4,,iv
5,,v
6,,vi
```

If so, you need to break this down into three steps:

1. Read the columns of all your CSVs, and aggregate those columns into a superset of all individual headers
2. Create **stacked.csv** and write the superset header
3. Read each CSV and write its values in their respective column names under the superset header in **stacked.csv**

```py
import csv

file_names = [
    'file1.csv',
    'file2.csv',
]


def print_debug(e, row, fname, super_list):
    if not 'dict contains fields' in str(e):
        raise

    print(f'''While trying to write row for file {fname}:
{row}

received error: "{e}"

Superset of headers is:
{super_list}
''')


# Aggregate headers
super_set = set()
for fname in  file_names:
    with open(fname, newline='') as f:
        reader = csv.DictReader(f)
        super_set.update(set(reader.fieldnames))

# DictReader needs this to be a list, not a set
super_set.add('file')
super_list = list(super_set)

with open('stacked.csv', 'w' , newline='') as f_out:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(f_out, fieldnames=super_list)
    writer.writeheader()

    for fname in  file_names:
        with open(fname, newline='') as f_in:
            reader = csv.DictReader(f_in)
            for row in reader:
                row['file'] = fname
                try:
                    writer.writerow(row)
                except ValueError as e:
                    print_debug(e, row, fname, super_list)
                except:
                    raise
```

When I run that against my two sample inputs, I get:

| c1 | c2 | c3 | file |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a |  | file1.csv |
| 2 | b |  | file1.csv |
| 3 | c |  | file1.csv |
| 4 |  | iv | file2.csv |
| 5 |  | v | file2.csv |
| 6 |  | vi | file2.csv |

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I implemented your code above and got the following error: "ValueError: dict contains fields not in fieldnames: None". Any idea what might be causing this?

Comment: Do your CSVs have headers? If they don't, this won't work.

Comment: Yes, they all have headers (I assume you are referring to field names).

Comment: That error is probably coming from the last line `writer.writerow(row)`, it means that there's a field in `row` that doesn't exist in `super_set`/`super_list`. If you're iterating the same list of files in Step 1 as in Step 3, I don't see how that's possible. I've added some exception handling and print debugging to try and help you find the file, and the header, that's not being collect in `super_set`.

Comment: BTW, for your own testing, modify your list of files to try and stack just the first two files and make sure at least that works.